# How to give relative path in .js on linux platform?

Tags: javascript

I have Web UI developed in simple HTML and .js with `lighttpd` as web server and it is on linux based device.

I need to keep my **main.html** file in root directory and javascript files in js folder.

While running program it reads the javascript from js folder and the javascript accessing config files from other directories (/etc/config/myconfig). While accessing this file application giving error as 403 since I am using `XMLHttpRequest`, but it works when I keep myconfig file in root directory i.e with the main.html.

Please suggest is there any way to tell javascript to read file from /etc/config directory.

Answer (score 0):

Error 403 :

> 403 Forbidden
>   The request was a valid request, but the server is refusing to respond to it.[2] Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference.[2] On servers where authentication is required, this commonly means that the provided credentials were successfully authenticated but that the credentials still do not grant the client permission to access the resource (e.g., a recognized user attempting to access restricted content).

You need give your script access to read from the directory(/etc/config).
Read about `chmod/chown` commands.